# Che cosa vuol dire "ammazzucculire"?

Tags: word-meaning, verbs, regional

Nel romanzo *Vita* di Melania G. Mazzucco ho letto:

> Le voci incattiviscono, parlano della pupàtella di Agnello, cioè di Vita – che tiene solo nove anni ma quanto si farà bella quann’**ammazzucculisce** già si vedette.

Immagino si tratti di una voce di origine dialettale perché non ho trovato questo verbo in nessun dizionario. Comunque, 
sapreste spiegarmi il significato di "ammazzucculire" in questo passaggio?

Comment: Non conosco il napoletano :) Ho come il sospetto che sia una specie di crasi del tipo "ammazzare con gli occhi" nel senso che anche se la bambina ha solo nove anni già ha uno sguardo che ammalia. Ma il mio  è davvero un tirare a indovinare.

Comment: Hai provato a cercare su un vocabolario dialettale? Per fonti di questo tipo temo diventi una risorsa necessaria...

Comment: @FedericoPoloni: Non so su quale vocabolario cercare.

Comment: Un vocabolario di napoletano, visto che il romanzo parla di due ragazzi napoletani mi pare?

Comment: @FedericoPoloni: Veramente questi due ragazzi sono di Tufo, una frazione di Minturno. Ma i personaggi sono italiani di varie procedenze emigrati agli Stati Uniti.

Comment: Comunque mi sembra il caso di fare un tentativo con un dizionario di napoletano. Da quel poco che capisco, quella frase mi sembra più simile al napoletano che al romanesco. Così come la domanda "come si traduce X in italiano" è inaccettabile su questo sito senza aver prima guardato un vocabolario, personalmente penso che in un caso come questo dovrebbe essere necessario consultare un vocabolario di un qualche dialetto della zona per farsi un'idea. Queste frasi sono scritte più in dialetto che in italiano, mi sembra.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni: [Questo](https://flore.unifi.it/retrieve/handle/2158/864495/28769/Antonio%2520Vinciguerra%2520-%2520Il%2520Vocabolario%2520del%2520dialetto%2520napolitano%2520di%2520Emmanuele%2520Rocco%2520-%2520Studio%2520ed%2520edizione%2520critica%2520della%2520parte%2520inedita%2520F-Z%2520-%2520Tesi%2520di%2520dottorato.pdf) è l'unico vocabolario di napoletano più o meno completo che sono riuscita a trovare ma, purtroppo, è soltanto della F alla Z.